# How to fake the source when navigating to a site

Tags: web, hyperlink

I want to see how I can emulate when I go to a page eg: www.example.com make it believe that I came from www.mypage.com, does that seem possible?

I mean, browsing as a user, you use to navigate from a site to another and then, when you go to site A eg: wwww.mywebsiteisfunny.com from site B eg: www.amazing.com, site A tracks that you came from site B. Therefore I want to know if it is possible to "fake" my origin and make believe to site A that I came from site C eg: wwww.differentsite.com

Thnks!

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The secret is in the "referer" header of the HTTP request.

This Chrome Extension does what you want: https://github.com/wasimakram/innocuous

Source ref: https://elaineou.com/2017/01/19/how-the-twitter-app-bypasses-paywalls/